# javascript getHeight is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have two websites that use the same JavaScript file. One is a Joomla Site and the other one is a copy of the layout of that site.

The JavaScript contains the following two lines:

```
var header = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
var headerHeight = header.getHeight();
```

If I open the Joomla Site it works just fine, but if I open the other site it doesnt work. My firebug  console gives the following Error:

```
TypeError: header.getHeight is not a function
    var headerHeight = header.getHeight();
```

I used the script tool of my firebug to look at the header and it seems like all the javascript functions that should be there are missing.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.getHeight()` is not js native method.
You can use `clientHeight` or `offsetHeight` native properties for DOM elements.

Comment: That also works and is probably an easier solution than the other one.

Answer (score 1):

`getHeight()` is not a standard method for DOM elements and is (most probably) a Prototype method here. While you might have `prototype.js` included in Joomla - it's not there on the non-Joomla site. 
The fix would be simply to *include* prototype.js along with your js file:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.1.0/prototype.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to get height:

```
var height = window.getComputedStyle(header)['height'];
```

Answer (score 0):

They are probably using a library which augments the prototype of `HTMLElement`, which the other side does not. This is nowadays considered bad practice anyway.